# Doctrine Behavior / Templates: Is there a way overwrite or load data into the invoking Doctrine_Record from a Doctrine_Template?

Tags: doctrine

Hy!

I'm new to the Doctrine library. I'm trying to take advantage of the [Doctrine Behavior](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors/en) (Templating) system to build a Authenticable behavior but I ran into a few problems.

**This is how i wanted to declare it:**

```
class BaseAdminUser extends Doctrine_Record{
public function setTableDefinition(){
   // ...
   }

public function setUp(){
  // ...
  $this->actAs(new Doctrine_Template_Authenticatable());
  }
}
```

**This is how i wanted to use it:**

In my admin *bootstrap* file:

```
// ...
$admin = new AdminUser();
if(!$admin->login_check()){
  redirect("login.php");
}else{
  // $admin->id is available
  }
```

In my admin *login.php* page:

```
// ...
if($data = $_POST){
  $admin->login($data); 
  }
```

I wanted my template to use Native PHP Sessions (using `$_SESSION`) to do the following:

1. upon login set a session and save the record `Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY` in it
2. upon instantiation of Record and Template check if the session data exists
   and load the invoking Record with the id from the session

One approach i tried was to re-route the $invoker. That doesn't work.

```
class Doctrine_Template_Authenticatable extends Doctrine_Template{ 
// ...
public function setUp(){  
  // ...  
  if(isset($session_data['id'])){  
     $invoker = &$this->getInvoker();  
     $invoker = $this->getTable()->find($session_data['id']);  
     }  
  }
// ...
}
```

I've looked trough the Doctrine_Record API Documentation and i could not find a function which would load (hydrate) a different table row into a object based on id or otherwise.
There's `fromArray($arr)` and `hydrate($arr, $overwrite)`:

```
Doctrine_Record::fromArray(string array, bool deep))
Doctrine_Record::hydrate(array data, boolean overwriteLocalChanges)
```

But that is fake and would just load the data without the id.

```
$this->getInvoker()->hydrate($session_data);  
// (...)
echo $admin->id; // empty


$this->getInvoker()->fromArray($session_data);
// Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Table_Exception' with message 'Unknown relation alias id'
```

**My question is:**
Is there a way overwrite or load data into the invoking `Doctrine_Record` from a `Doctrine_Template` ?